# Gerrit ignore negative vote from jenkins

Tags: gerrit

I have a Jenkins setup to be triggered by Gerrit once a patch is updated. Verified label has a negative rating from Jenkins. This rating is irrelevant in my case and so I just want to ignore it for this one time. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to ignore the vote but it is possible to delete it if you have the correct access rights.
After this you can vote +1 Verified and you should be able to submit.

Of course, this all depends on the server configuration and access rights.

In our case we have given some developers the rights to delete and vote on the Verified label of other developers, this is a way to get around Jenkins issues.